# Android and React Native top navigation Bar

Tags: android, react-native, uinavigationbar, react-navigation

I would like to ask you about section selected on pictures below. [image]
[image]

What is the name of this section and how I can style it in React Native? At now my APK have an ugly white bar and I can't see level of battery or WiFi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area with the battery and time is called the [status bar](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/status-bars/). In most cases I've seen, the status bar is given a set height depending on the platform from ReactNative's `Platform` module.

Afterwards, you can pass this height to a `<View>` and add additional styling.

```
import { Platform, ... } from 'react-native'

...code...

const STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = Platform.select({ ios: 20, android: 24 })

export default class MyComponent extends Component {

  ...code...

  render() {
    <View style={{ height: STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT, ...more styles here... }} />
    <View>

      ...code...

    </View>
  }
}
```